Upgrading MariaDB in Cpanel/WHM failed
I saw a warning of endlife for Mariadb and tried to upgrade that to the last version from the WHM panel
I got this and I fear to go future
Cpanel on Almalinux 8.1
The system was not able to ensure the availability of the “MariaDB-client” package: (XID gfpc96) “/usr/bin/yum” reported error code “1” when it ended: Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'imunify360': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Obtained version information from system.
Proceeding with MySQL/MariaDB upgrade despite the following:
Critical: In MariaDB 10.4 and later, the mysql.global_priv table has replaced the mysql.user table. The mysql.user table is converted into a view of the mysql.global_priv table during the database upgrade. The dedicated mariadb.sys user is created as the definer of the new mysql.user view.
Critical: The "mytop" package is not compatible due to MDEV-22552. If "mytop" is installed, the upgrade process will uninstall the "mytop" package.
Normal: All binaries previously beginning with `mysql` now begin with `mariadb`. Symlinks are created for the corresponding mysql commands to ensure backwards compatibility. Usually that should not cause any changed behavior, but when starting the MariaDB server via systemd, or via the `mysqld_safe` script symlink, the server process will now always be started as `mariadbd`,
not`mysqld`. Any 3rd party software or scripts looking for the `mysqld` name in the system process list
must now look for `mariadbd` instead. Normal: MariaDB 10.6 introduced a new reserved word: OFFSET. This can no longer be used as an identifier without being quoted.
Normal: From MariaDB 10.6, tables that are of the `COMPRESSED` row format are read-only by default. This is the first step towards removing write support and deprecating the feature. The `innodb_read_only_compressed` variable
must be set to `OFF` in order to make the tables writable.

What should I do?
I tried to update form whm panel web ui, got error and stoped to update until find a safe solution for this

I solve that, first, uninstall the Imunify360, then updated the almalinux to last version, then I used command to update the cpanel, after that I run upgrade mariadb and reboot the server and it was fixed
